# jQuery to remove <p><br><br></p>

Tags: html, jquery

What would be the jQuery to remove.

```
<p>
    <br>
    <br>
</p>
```

I have this

```
$('p').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).html()) === '<br>') $(this).remove();
});
```

which removes

```
<p>
    <br>
</p>
```

but adding another br like so

```
$('p').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).html()) === '<br><br>') $(this).remove();
});
```

doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As a more general approach, try this:

```
$("p").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $.trim($this.text()) == "") $this.remove();
});
```

This will remove all paragraphs whose only textual content is whitespace - in other words, "empty" paragraph elements.

Note that this may be a little over-zealous, if for instance you have a paragraph that only contains an image. You may need to adjust a little to allow for this case.

Answer (score 2):

try this, see output

It will remove every p tag that contains line breaks

```js
$("p").each(function(){
    if($(this).find('br').length)
     $(this).remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
 this is<br/>
  with line breaks<br/>
  remove this p tag
  </p>

<p>
no breaks
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the original question and for some reason it has me as an unregistered user. The first answer works but I can't choose it as the answer or up vote it. :-( I also wondered what would be the work around to include an img within a paragraph tag just in case.

The second answer unfortunately in my case wouldn't work because it would remove legit paragraphs where the forum I'm using (and don't have access to the source) automatically adds the br tags within legit paragraphs